# Xamarin Android - Select image with path

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've got this code, but I'm not sure how to select images from DCIM in Xamarin Android.

```
var SysLog = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SysLog);

        byte[] ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes("Internal storage/DCIM/Camera/img.jpg");
        string _base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
        SysLog.Text = _base64String;
```

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to read an image from the photo gallery/camera?

Comment: Should be similar to doing it in native android. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218928/how-can-i-access-the-camera-roll-photos-on-android